# Proving the Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $\{{E_k}\}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ be a countable family of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and that
>   \begin{equation} % Equation (1)
> \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}m(E_k)<\infty
> \end{equation}
>   Let
>   \begin{align*}
> E&=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d:x\in E_k, \text{ for infinitely many $k$ }\} \\
> &= \underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\lim \sup}(E_k).\\
> \end{align*}
>
> (a) Show that $E$ is measurable
>
> (b) Prove $m(E)=0.$

My Proof Attempt:

*Proof*. Let the assumptions be as above. We will prove part (a) by showing that
\begin{equation*}
E=\cap^{\infty}_{n=1}\cup_{k\geq n}E_k. 
\end{equation*}
Hence, E would be measurable, since for every
fixed $n$, $\cup_{k\geq n}E_k$ is measurable since it is a countable union of measurable sets.
Then $\cap^{\infty}_{n=1}\cup_{k\geq n}E_k$ is the countable intersection of measurable sets.

From here, we shall denote $\cup_{k\geq n}E_k$ as $S_n$.
 Let $x\in \cap^{\infty}_{n=1}S_n$.  Then $x\in S_n$ for every
$n\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $x$ must be in $E_k$ for infinitely many $k$, otherwise there would exist
an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\notin S_N$. Leaving $x$ out of the intersection.
Thus, $\cap^{\infty}_{n=1}S_n\subset E$.

Conversely, let $x\in E.$ 
Then $x\in E_k$ for infinitely many $k$. Therefore, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$,
 $x\in S_n$. Otherwise, $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\notin S_N$.
Which would imply that $x\in E_k$ for only $k$ up to $N$, i.e. finitely many. A contradiction.
Therefore, $x\in \cap^{\infty}_{n=1}S_n$. Hence, they contain one
another and equality holds. This proves part (1).

Now for part (b). Fix $\epsilon>0$. We need to show that there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
m(S_N)\leq \epsilon
\end{equation*}
Then since $E\subset S_N$, monotonicity of the measure would imply that $m(E)\leq \epsilon$.
Hence, proving our desired conclusion as we let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Since $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}m(E_k)<\infty$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\left| \sum^{\infty}_{k=N}m(E_k)\right |\leq \epsilon
\end{equation*}
By definition, 
\begin{equation*}
m(S_N)=m(\cup_{k\geq N}E_k)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=N}m(E_k)
\end{equation*}
Thus, $m(S_N)\leq \epsilon$. This completes our proof.

---

Any corrections of the proof, or comments on style of the proof are welcome and appreciated. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proof is almost perfect, only in the end it is not necessary true that $m(\cup_{k\geq N}E_k)=\sum_{k=N}^\infty m(E_k)$ since the sets $E_k$ might not be pairwise disjoint. So the measure of the union is only **at most** the sum of measures. But in our case it doesn't change anything for the proof, since we anyway get $m(S_N)\leq\sum_{k=N}^\infty m(E_k)\leq\epsilon$. Still it is important to remember the correct properties of measure.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is fine, modulo the comment in the other answer. For another approach, which I think is the way Rudin does it, note that $x\in E$ if and only if the series $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}1_{E_k}(x)$ diverges.

Set $s_n(x)=\sum^{n}_{k=1}1_{E_k}(x).$ Then, $s_n(x)\to s(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}1_{E_k}(x)$ and the monotone converge theorem gives $\sum^{n}_{k=1}m(E_k)\to \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}m(E_k)<\infty.$ Thus, $s\in L^1(m)$, so the series converges almost everywhere $m$. That is, the set on which it diverges, namely $E$, has Lebesgue measure zero and so $m(E)=0.$

Remark: since we proved that $m(E)=0,$ we get part $(a)$ for free.